# Multiple Image IF file_exists query

Tags: php

I am trying to do a multiple if file_exists query and I just cannot seem to get it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<? if (file_exists("images/one.jpg" || "images/two.jpg")) { ?>
Yes, there is either file one.jpg OR file two.jpg OR both are present.
<? } else { ?>
No dice, Neither files are there.
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate `file_exists` calls for different files:

```
<? if (file_exists("images/one.jpg") || file_exists("images/two.jpg")) { ?>
Yes, there is either file one.jpg OR file two.jpg OR both are present.
<? } else { ?>
No dice, Neither files are there.
<? } ?>
```

Comment: I knew I was close. Really appreciate your help @vee

Answer (score 1):

If you have more files to detect, using too many `||` operator is ugly. You better store them in an array, then use `foreach` to test if any one exists.

```
$files = array("images/ong.jpg", "images/two.jpg");
$exists = false;

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        $exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

echo exists ? "Yes, there is either file one.jpg OR file two.jpg OR both are present." : "No dice, Neither files are there.";
```